# Change a TabItem's name by double clicking the name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` and I'm trying to allow the user to change the tab name... but only when the name is double-clicked.  That way, users can click the different tab names to simply change the active tab, but also change the tab name if they desire.

**What I've tried so far** is to capture the  `MouseDoubleClick` and `LostFocus` events, then set the "Focusable" property to be true only when the tab name is double clicked.  The problem with this method is the `LostFocus` event is firing *immediately* after the double click, presumably because the focus is being set to the content of the TabItem.

My tab control XAML:

```
    <Mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl x:Name="ViewTabs" DataContext="{Binding MyTabsViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <Mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyTabViewModel}">
                <TextBox x:Name="TabNameTextBox" 
                         Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         MouseDoubleClick="TabNameTextBox_MouseDoubleClick"
                         LostFocus="TabNameTextBox_LostFocus"
                         Cursor ="Arrow"/>        
            </DataTemplate>
        </Mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
```

Code behind events `MouseDoubleClick` and `Lost Focus`:

```
    private void TabNameTextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.Focusable = true;
        textBox.Focus();
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void TabNameTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.Focusable = false;
    }
```

<sub>I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898951/wpf-tabitem-lost-focus-event) where the asker couldn't get the `Lost Focus` event to fire.  In my situation, it is firing before I expect it to.</sub>

Comment: I would try doing this the MVVM way, basically add a property to `viewModels:MyTabViewModel` something like `IsRenaming`, then when you handle the mouse double click change the value of `IsRenaming` which will basically hide a label and show a textbox using bindings in the `Mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl.ItemTemplate` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following to work with a standard WPF `TabControl`. My guess is that it should work for a `Mah:MetroAnimatedTabControl` as well.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" LostFocus="textBox_LostFocus" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contents}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 1" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 2" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 3" });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (items == null)
                items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            return items;
        }
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2 && e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as UIElement);
            (sender as UIElement).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            grid.Children[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            grid.Children[0].Focus();
            ((TextBox)grid.Children[0]).SelectAll();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as UIElement);
        (sender as UIElement).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        grid.Children[1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Item.cs:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Item()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Name))
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Contents)));
        }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name { get => name; set { name = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name))); } }

    public string Contents { get => $"Contents of {Name}"; }


}
```

Screenshot after I double-clicked the "Item 3" header name:

[image]